# How to specify the content-type and the content-transfer-encoding of a specific field in my JSON API response?

Tags: json, types, http-headers, base64

I'm developing an API which, given a request-body with certain contents, generates a document that can be in different formats (e.g. PDF, png, etc). Given that the document can be a binary file, the file is base64-encoded and placed within a JSON response that looks like this:

```json
{
   "document": "document base64-encoded"
}
```

The response might contain other fields but they are not relevant to the question.

**My question is:**

What is the best way to specify the content-type (e.g. PDF) and the content-encoding (e.g base64) of the field `document`?

I thought of some options but I would like to hear your recommendation.

**My options**

- Use header parameters `Content-Type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding`: I assume this option would be wrong as these parameters apply to the message itself which in this case is `application/json` without any encoding.
- Specify custom-parameters (e.g. `x-document-content-type` and `x-document-content-tranfer-encoding`.
- Include such metadata within the response-body like this:

```json
{
   "document": {
      "content": "document base64-encoded",
      "type": "pdf",
      "encoding": "base64"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 layers of communication here, each with their own contract/protocol. Your own JSON API protocol, being sent over the HTTP protocol. You should stick to HTTP standards to comply with the contract of that layer, and it is up to you to define the contract of the JSON data.

The mentioned HTTP headers are used to tell the user-agent/client what the MIME-type of the accompanying HTTP body is. This must be application/JSON to comply with the HTTP standard. If you diver from this it will not be valid HTTP traffic anymore and a regular, well configured HTTP client wouldn't be able to consume your API.

The JSON body inside the HTTP message can be filled with whatever you find is necessary for a consumer of your API to use the encoded contents. You are defining your own contract here, so it is really up to your needs and that of the consumers of your api.

Do you use other content encodings as base64? If so, then you can specify the encoding of the data.

Do you provide multiple different file types? Then it's useful to add the content-type of the encoded data. Be aware that the header of the encoded content might already contain information about the type of the contents of the file.

P.s. it would probably be better to provide the "type" as you name it, as a mime-type. This is more common as a known standard for defining content types.